# Unescaping string? in Shopify

Tags: schema, settings, shopify

I have 8 feature products added in my settings_schema.json . I want to output them by for loop by adding number on the end of settings.feature_product[incrementing integer]

This is my settings schema

```
{
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product1",
    "label": "Feature Product 1"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product2",
    "label": "Feature Product 2"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product3",
    "label": "Feature Product 3"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product4",
    "label": "Feature Product 4"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product5",
    "label": "Feature Product 5"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product6",
    "label": "Feature Product 6"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product7",
    "label": "Feature Product 7"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "feature_product8",
    "label": "Feature Product 8"
  }
```

This is the code in my snippet

```
      {% for i in (1..8) %}
        {% if i <= 8 %}
          <div class="case_item">
            {% assign case_var = 'settings.feature_product' | append: i | strip_html %}
            {{ all_products[case_var].title }} 
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work :( I tried to print the case_var and the result is..
settings.feature_product1
settings.feature_product2
.
.
settings.feature_product3

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for i in (1..8) %}
    {% capture productid %}feature_product{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
    {% if settings[productid] != '' %}

        <div class="case_item">

        {% assign productslug = settings[productid] %}

          <h3>{{ all_products[productslug].title }}</h3>

          <em>{{ all_products[productslug].price | money }}</em>


        </div>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```